# UIScrollView above UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

Please check below a simplified version of my view hierarchy. The scroll view has a clear background and covers the two buttons (1 & 2):

```
UIView
    | UIView
         | UIButton 1
    | UIButton 2
    | UIScrollView (pinned to the superview edges - clear color)
```

At the beginning I wasn't receiving tap gestures for the buttons as the scrollview is covering them. So I tried to put the scroll view in a container view and override the `pointInside` method.

```
class PassThroughView: UIView {
//...
var buttons = [UIView]()

override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    return buttons.all { view in
        return view.isHidden ||
            !view.isUserInteractionEnabled ||
            !view.point(inside: convert(point, to: view), with: event)
    }
}
```

}

The `PassThoughView` holda the array of buttons (1 & 2). The new hierarchy becomes:

```
UIView
    | UIView
         | UIButton 1
    | UIButton 2
    | PassThoughView (pinned to the superview edges - clear color)
         | UIScrollView (pinned to the superview edges - clear color)
```

This solved the first part of the problem. I was able to tap on the buttons as well as drag the scroll view.

The bad part is that I can't scroll anymore unless I start the dragging outside the buttons. The buttons are a bit large and this makes the experience not very friendly.

Is there a way to allow the tap gestures to traverse the scroll view and allow the scroll view to receive pan gestures even if the touches started within one of the buttons

**Edit:**

I hope that the pictures explain a little bit what's the purpose of this. I need to put a scroll view over all the views so that I can increase the scrollable area. (This is very specific to my case). The user might want to initiate a scroll within the take picture button and if the gesture is tap we take a picture.

[image]

Comment: Could we go back a bit? Why on earth would you put a scroll view in _front_ of buttons that you want the user to be able to tap? What were you _really_ trying to accomplish by this very strange interface? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish it. :) For example, it is easy to put the buttons in front of the scroll view without allowing them to move when you scroll. Wouldn't that solve the problem? And wouldn't it be a more understandable interface?

Comment: @matt I have edited the question. Hope that it makes sense now

Comment: This is an unusual UX for an iOS app. Basically no-one expects to start scrolling from a button, and only scroll the view behind, while the button stays on the same position.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right you need a gesture dependency. The pan gesture of the UIScollView should have a higher priority than the tap gesture of the UIButton.

In case of a UIButton I have no idea yet how to solve it, because a UIButton is a UIControl without using a UIGestureRecognizer. But if you use an own UIView with a UITapGestureRecognizer instead it should be possible.

Get the UIPanGestureRecognizer from the UIScrollView by using the property

`var panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer { get }` see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619425-pangesturerecognizer)

Now you are able to combine both recognizer by using

`func require(toFail otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)` see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-require)

The final code line should look like that:

```
tapGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: panGestureRecognizer)
```